# Adding vsphere storage provider to a running k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, vmware-vsphere

We followed the k8s documents to create Highly Available clusters with kubeadm   https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/.

Our cluster is built with 3 masters & 5 workers using VM guests and RHEL as an OS.

We were not aware at the time about using vSphere as a cloud provider for storage ..
We would like to add vSphere as a cloud provider..

Looking around all the info assumes that we will add vSphere as a cloud provider at the time of building the cluster as illustrated in  https://cloud-provider-vsphere.sigs.k8s.io/tutorials/kubernetes-on-vsphere-with-kubeadm.html  or  https://theithollow.com/2020/01/08/deploy-kubernetes-on-vsphere/

Anyone can help me how to add vSphere to an exiting running cluster.

Comment: What issues are you having following the instructions?

Comment: In both links above ,, you first create a configuration file and run kubeadm init --config using that file and build the first matser node in the cluster. However , in may case I already have the cluster up and running so I am not sure how can I add the external provided to the existing cluster.